# How to remove all objects form existing array using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

A function that pushing objects into an array has the problem that does not remove objects.

This is code which is pushing the object's to the array

```
$( "#reset" ).click(function() {
    result = true;
    checkoldval(result);
});

var arr = [];
function checkoldval(current_val){
 var total = 0;
 if(current_val == true){
   arr = []; 
}else{
      arr.push({'total':total ,'current':current_val});
  }
}
```

it's not working arr gatting obj even if condition true

output :

```
 [{total: 0, current: 14}
 {total: 0, current: 13}]
```

Comment: What is value of the `current_val`?

Comment: Look at the code - `checkoldval(result);`

Comment: Everything working good in your code, please create test  `checkoldval(true);console.log(arr);checkoldval(10);checkoldval(100);console.log(arr);checkoldval(true);console.log(arr);`

Comment: @Shuvo The value is true

Comment: @Reporter, did you declare the `result` variable somewhere else? Or this line `result = true;` should be replaced with `var result = true;` ?

Comment: @Shuvo its object {value: "somevalue"} but problem is not for pushing

Comment: @Shuvo I think the second option is correct. May be using let instead of var.

Comment: @Greg-- yes i have done with it but no solution

Comment: @Reporter the condition also excuted properly

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] (preferable as [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) that shows the actual behavior/problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to remove objects it will not work

Its working good, check other part of code, your function is working good

```js
var arr = [];
function checkoldval(current_val){
  var total = 0;
  if(current_val == true){
   arr = []; 
  }else{
      arr.push({'total':total ,'current':current_val});
  }
}

checkoldval(true); // clear
console.log('must be empty arr=', arr); // empty
checkoldval(10); // add 10
checkoldval(100); // add 100
console.log('must contain two items  arr=',arr); // arr with two items
checkoldval(true); // clear
console.log('must be empty  arr=',arr); // empty
```